How can I bypass a smart RO water purifier system installed at home?
I want to bypass the smart RO water purifier system connectivity with the actual server. So I can use it without recharging it & save money. When recharge done then a certain validity end date comes up on the device app. I want to bypass that.
Tried nothing but trying to find a way out.

How is this supposed to be a question about software? Your question seems quite off-topic
